# Add New tab to Sidekick in CQ5

Tags: aem

I want to add a new tab in the CQ5 sidekick & then a sub-menu inside it. How can this be done.

For Example I need a Custom tab in Sidekick after workflow tab menu and a set of buttons inside it. Any suggestions regarding this?